# could not invoke FileReaderModule.readAsDataURL null failed to allocate a *** byte allocation with *** free bytes and **MB until OOM,target footprint

Tags: android, react-native, crash, out-of-memory

```
import { Storage} from 'aws-amplify';
const s3Response = await Storage.put(blob1.data.name, blob1, {
          contentType: blob1.data.type,
        });
```

When upload the large size of video then app crash in React Native .